# Advantages that Git# (GitSharp) will bring over current alternatives on Windows?

Tags: git, version-control, gitsharp

With their August 2010 release (they have a very clean road-map on their site), what are the advantages [Git#](http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/GitSharp) (or [GitSharp](http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/GitSharp)) and applications based on it have over current alternatives on Windows? I mean advantages that *could not have been possible* without Git#.

**Edit:** Question wasn't framed properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that it makes sense to talk about advantages of one over the other, given that they are completely different things: MSysGit is a program to be used by humans, Git# is a library to be used by machines.

That's like asking what the advantages are of a slice of pizza over the International Space Station.

Comment: You can both eat and afford a slice of pizza.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've framed my question better now. Like, I use TortoiseGit at times. Would using GitSharp.Demo have advantages over it in terms of core features (like speed)?

Answer (score 0):

For the end user it doesn't make a difference except that GitSharp isn't complete yet and therefor is not able to provide all the git features.

For the applications programmer it does make a huge difference because you can access a git repository via a clean and simple API and do not need to format command line commands, start msysgit in a seperate process and parse the output.

Comment: That's one thing. How does GitSharp (of whatever is ready as of now) compare with msysGit in terms of performance. Git was designed for performance.

Comment: We haven't even benchmarked gitsharp's performance yet ;)
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

We want a library to reduce **startup overhead** of launching a process and **avoid parsing result** from stdout. That's what GitSharp does in a high level way.

I can see when a lot of git.exe launch at the same time (like CruiseControl.NET automatic build), they significantly slow down my PC.